# Probleme to access my google account with youtube API on a subdomain

Tags: youtube-api

I have an issue with the youtube API.

Actually, it works fine on a server (http://mysite.com), but i would like to create another API (or use the same if it's possible) on another server (with the url: http://dev.mysite.com, so it's juste a subdomain).

The probleme is, it doesn't works on the second server, (i use the php Zend library for the both).

When i click on the link witch should give me back a token after the user accept the autorization, i have an error message, something like "we can't access your googleaccount account because another website tried to acces it and sent a wrong request... AuthSub target path prefix does not match the provided "next" URL. " (but it still work on the first server (http://mysite.com)).

I registered the good redirect URI in my client and in the code, i do not understand...

Do you know how to resolve this problem ?

When you want to create an application on many subdomains, do you have to create one product and one client_id by subdomain or have we to create one product and one client_id for each subdomain ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: I just test to change my redirect uri in my code, i remplaced the "http://dev.mysite.com" by "http://mysite.com" and it works, however, i use the dev-key and the client_id of the product and the redirect_uri whitch lead to "http://dev.mysite.com"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using the Auth Google Javascript library